# Is there anyway to use regex with jstree.searchColumn?

Tags: javascript, grid, jstree

I am using [jstree grid](https://github.com/deitch/jstree-grid) and `searchColumn` API to perform search. I would like to know if there is any way to perform the search in regex input?

In the code of the library, there is a check for `search_callback` but I do not know how to provide one from the outside call.

Answer (score 0):

It was my bad. The API state that we can provide the search_callback directly when initialize the columns